# Writing Web methods to Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, apache-pig

I am not from Java ,so my question may be very easy but I need clear steps how to implement.

**Existing project** : Webmethods connecting to Oracle Data base to fetch certain properties file and insert log information into some tables.

**Problem:** Many a times data base goes down and hence delays in execution.

**New Requirement:** We have to replace existing oracle table with Hbase. I have writen code write file into Hbase using Pig. But I really don't know how to write the real time data into Hbase.

I found using Java client or Thrift connection I can write. I need very detailed explanation. I have to submit for an Project. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have knowledge of Row oriented database and Hbase is column oriented database.But we have apache Phoenix.

Apache Phoenix is a relational database layer over HBase delivered as a client-embedded JDBC driver targeting low latency queries over HBase data. Apache Phoenix takes your SQL query, compiles it into a series of HBase scans, and orchestrates the running of those scans to produce regular JDBC result sets. The table metadata is stored in an HBase table and versioned, such that snapshot queries over prior versions will automatically use the correct schema. Direct use of the HBase API, along with coprocessors and custom filters, results in performance on the order of milliseconds for small queries, or seconds for tens of millions of rows.

This can easily solve your problem.
http://phoenix.apache.org/

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:[zookeeper]");
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        stmt.executeUpdate("create table test (mykey integer not null primary key, mycolumn varchar)");
        stmt.executeUpdate("upsert into test values (1,'Hello')");
        stmt.executeUpdate("upsert into test values (2,'World!')");
        con.commit();

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from test");
        rset = statement.executeQuery();
        while (rset.next()) {
            System.out.println(rset.getString("mycolumn"));
        }
        statement.close();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok.Thats grt Kishore. So Using jdbc connectivity we will be able to write data in Hbase through phoenix.

Comment: Kishore, Thanks a lot for the answer. I was looking, how to use Java client to write data into Hbase.